# UWP OneDrive access with HttpClient (WebDav commands)

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, webdav, onedrive

I'm trying to figure out, how the the Access to OneDrive works, when adding a netshare on my Windows 10 PC with the "WebDav" URI (https://d.docs.live.net/CustomerID). So it seems that basically the Access works with WebDav commands, but the authentication seems to be with Microsoft Passport. Now inside my UWP test app i can Access WebDav Servers with Basic and Digest authentication, but i can't Access OneDrive. What exactly do i need to implement, to authenticate with OneDrive?

Thanks in advice

Comment: Did you try to use [One Drive API](https://dev.onedrive.com/getting-started.htm)? There are samples also available to help you how this is done.

Comment: Thank you, i already read this, but i search the best possible way to use webdav commands with a httpclient from the "Windows.Web.Http" Namespace, for accessing OneDrive. So is this the only way?

Comment: I have 0 knowledge in `WebDAV` but Integrating an UWP app with `OneDrive` using SDK and API's are very easy in my experience.

Comment: I've used the SDK already in another Project, so the usage of the API is an alternative to the SDK using HttpClient?

Comment: Yes. I can say its an alternate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing, i figured out, how to retreive an access token for sending webdav-requests to onedrive, which works the same way, as a connected network share to onedrive in windows does. Fiddler helped me to understand the process of authentication.

Thanks for all the answers.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest checking out the [OneDrive SDK](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp) - it has samples that include authentication. Alternatively, since you're writing a UWP you could consider the [UWP Community Toolkit](http://docs.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/) that has OneDrive support via UWP file-like interfaces.

Comment: Thank you i saw the SDK and i used it already for another project, but since my library for webdav access is already implemented, i search a way to extend it as simple as possible, to reuse my library for all the webdav commands.